# Cloudwatch alarm about accountwide concurrency limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm, cloudwatch-alarms

I would like to create a cloudwatch alarm to alert before reaching the concurrency limit of the account. I have over 10 lambda functions, thus I can't use the ConcurrentExecutions metric provided by AWS due to the limitation about the number of metrics that can be used for a single alarm.

Reference to the limitation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_limits.html
"Alarms based on metric math expressions can have up to 10 metrics."

I have looked at composite alarms, but that would not solve my problem. I want to monitor all of my lambdas at once and alert when the sum of the concurrentExecutions metrics is greater than 900.

Any idea how to overcome this limitation? I would like to get notified before throttling my lambda functions.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you can use the `Across All Functions ConcurrentExecutions` metrics. The documentation says: `Across All Functions (none) – View aggregate metrics for all functions in the current AWS Region.` - [monitoring-metrics-console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html#monitoring-metrics-console). If I understand it correctly, the quota that you mention is for alarm that use `math expressions`. That is if you configured it manually and use the `Add math` function and select each Lambda manually.

Comment: Thank you very much. By leaving dimensions blank will use the ConcurrentExecutions metric for "across all functions". This seems to be a solution for my problem.

Comment: Great! You're welcome! And thanks for mentioning the Dimension! I'll be putting the answer on a separate comment so you can accept it and mark this question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a metric called *Across All Functions* in CloudWatch metrics.

The documentation says:

> Across All Functions (none) – View aggregate metrics for all functions in the current AWS Region. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html#monitoring-metrics-console

To create an Alarm for this, go to **CloudWatch > Metrics > All > AWS Namespace > Lambda > Across All Functions**

Select **ConcurrentExecutions** then click on **Create alarm**.
[image]

If you are creating the Alarm via code, sdk or cli, you can leave the Dimension empty since you don't need to specify the Function name.